# Dragging an object across the screen not dragging consistently

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in Android Studio where I am dragging a block around the screen, but for some reason the dragging does not function properly.

Here's what it is supposed to look like: [Video](https://youtu.be/Rliwg0sELJo?t=14m)

And here's what mine looks like: [Video](https://youtu.be/bnP6j4z7g84)

For some reason, my dragging only seems to be dragging the box half the distance of the cursor. I'm not sure why this would be, since I followed the code in the tutorial exactly, but I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction with making this fix. Here is my code of the class I believe needs to be adjusted somehow:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private MainThread thread;
private RectPlayer player;
private Point playerPoint;
private ObstacleManager obstacleManager;

public GamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    player = new RectPlayer(new Rect(100,100,200,200), Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    playerPoint = new Point(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(200, 350, 75, Color.BLACK);

    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    try{
        thread.setRunning(false);
        thread.join();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    retry = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
    }

    return true;
}

public void update() {
    player.update(playerPoint);
    obstacleManager.update();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    player.draw(canvas);
    obstacleManager.draw(canvas);
}
```

}

My guess is that it is something in the onTouchEvent I need to change, but again, I'm really unsure. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a couple hours staring at my code and trying random changes, I've finally found the fix. I really don't know what caused the issue in the first place, but I have the solution. My initial suspicion of onTouchEvent function being the issue was correct. The correct code is:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            playerPoint.set((int)event.getX()*2,(int) event.getY()*2);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The only thing I changed was I multiplied the x and y values by 2 when setting the player point. Again, I'm not quite sure why it worked the way it did in the first place, but it works as intended now.